# Skip port healthcheck in App Service on deployment?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed a Node.js application on an App Service in Azure. And it seems to stop at this step on the deployment. Now, obviously it seems that it is trying to ping to the port 8080:

`2019-12-13 10:55:17.285 ERROR - Container xxx for site xxx did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 230.4463132 sec`

`2019-12-13 10:55:17.288 ERROR - Container xx didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.`

But, the application in question is a bot and exposes NO ports. Is there a possibility to "skip" this healthcheck or am I required to open the port up in my application?

Comment: Hey I'm facing the exact same issue. Did you find a walk-around or other services that are more suitable for these kind of things? Thanks

Comment: Hey @EricHua. There isn't really a workaround, so I had to actually open up my port to get it to work.

Comment: @Sfync Yea, me too. I had to embed my Java worker application into a Tomcat server :(

Comment: I'll hold my breath for Azure to provide a "do as I say" work-around.  Until then, a dummy Kestrel it is.

Answer (score 0):

Azure container apps work just fine for this `headless` scenario (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/container-apps).

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for asking question! If I have understood right container is taking long time to start, as the default time is 230 sec but we can configure the limit up to a 1800 sec by adding an app setting called WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT and set it to the number of seconds would like to wait for the  container to start (up to a maximum of 1800 sec)
Also check container logs: If "docker run" command is run and there are not any error messages here. Just double check on Node.js engine is listening on port you are using. You need to EXPOSE instruction in your Dockerfile to expose the port.

You may refer to below links might be helpful: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/09/08/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-faq#custom-containers

Comment: The thing is, I am deploying a bot for discord. This bot needs NO ports to be "online". That's why I have no ports that are exposed. I was able to fix it by opening up a port and letting it check the port for healthchecks, but I what I wondered was if there was an option to skip that healthcheck because I didn't want to expose a port just for that, but maybe my mindset is wrong.

Comment: No, you haven't understood right :( The OP clearly states that the container starts on time, only it's not running a web server and therefore Azure mistakenly considers it to have failed. I'm in a similar situation and wish I didn't have to fire up an http server just for a workaround